# Fill W-8ben If the bank account is not mine

Tags: united-states, money-transfer, form-w-8-ben

I am not a US citizen or resident. I suppose to get money from a US company so I have to fill a W-8ben form. I want the company to transfer the money to a bank account of a friend of mine. In such case, when I fill the form should I add my name as the beneficial or my friend's ?

Comment: Note that I'd expect a competent employer to ask some serious questions if they're asked to send payments to an account the employee doesn't own.  That has the appearance of an attempt to circumvent the law (i.e. the employee owes child support and is trying to hide income from the government, the employee isn't actually able to work for the company, etc.).

Answer (score -1):

I suspect you would need to enter your friend's name in the payment information section, because when the money is deposited, the bank account is identified by the name and account number among other things. I believe it's a safety measure to prevent accidentally sending money to the wrong person. In any case, you usually can't just wire money to "John Doe at account X" if account X is actually held by Richard Poe.

However you should contact the HR department of the company, they can talk to accounting/payroll and decide what you should do depending on how your particular company actually executes the deposits.